# There was an unhandled error: 19.0.0 is not a valid SDK version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a problem when i use `react-native` to execute the application :

I am using `create-react-native-app` for creating my application and i get this error after i execute `npm start` command and open app in `expo` on my smart phone.

**The error** :

```
There was an unhandled error: 19.0.0 is not a valid SDK version. Options are 18.0.0, 17.0.0, 16.0.0, 15.0.0, 14.0.0, 13.0.0, 12.0.0, 11.0.0, UNVERSIONED.
```

**package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "app3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hello Expo!",
  "author": null,
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^19.0.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-19.0.0.tar.gz"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Expo SDK instead. I switched long ago and, so far, no regrets.

You can download it from here:

https://expo.io/tools

From there you can create new projects painlessly and I've never gotten such a warning using it.

**Edit:**

There is little to no results to this issue, but as was stated in https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native/issues/70#issuecomment-297657645

> If i modify app.json and use 15.0.0 it works to run npm start. Then (and this is where it gets strange) I can kill the process, change it back to 16.0.0, and restart it - and it works. I've had these exact steps happen to me on two fresh CRNA projects.

The next option you have is to uninstall and reinstall the expo APP in your device/simulator.

Comment: can you post the full error? Did the error happen without adding any code?

Comment: this is full error on expo : `There was an unhandled error: 19.0.0 is not a valid SDK version. Options are 18.0.0, 17.0.0, 16.0.0, 15.0.0, 14.0.0, 13.0.0, 12.0.0, 11.0.0, UNVERSIONED.`

Comment: Are you running on an emulator or a physical device? Is the expo app updated?

Comment: can you update your question with your packaje.json? I just created a fresh project with SDK 19 and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151617/discussion-between-enriquedev-and-543310).

Comment: @SaeedVaziry how did you resolve this issue? I think I'm running into exactly the same thing. Expo is at 23.0.0 in my package.json and app.json, but my device is saying `There was an unhandled error: 18.0.0 is not a valid SDK version. Options are 25.0.0, 24.0.0, 23.0.0, 22.0.0, 21.0.0, 19.0.0, UNVERSIONED.`

Answer (score 1):

I created a new app from scratch doing `exp init my-app` and I got the same error using android - ubuntu and I fixed by doing the following:

`npm i -g exp`

That's all, I had an older version of `expo` already installed, be sure you have the last one.

If you are not in a real device ( an emulator ) be sure you have the last version.

Start the app using the expo tools doing `exp start`

Answer (score 1):

Getting the same error on **android - emulator - expo SDK 24** and fixed it by manually uninstalling Expo from the emulator and then restarting the app.

More info: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/568

Answer (score 0):

I simply updated my expo in  the application store and that worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest expo APK for Android emulator from link https://apkpure.com/expo/host.exp.exponent and install it. This will make the app work for me.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this problem update your expo on your phone